# Boto3 listing files within an s3 object

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

is there a way to use boto3 to print the filenames within an s3 bucket object?

the bucket looks like this

1. Bucket

- Object1

  - File 1
  - File 2
- Object 2

  - File3
  - File4

Is there a way to use boto3 to print the names of files?

Comment: What do you mean by "the filenames within an s3 bucket object" -- are you saying that each object contains a list of filenames? Is it a text file? If so, you could read the contents of the file and then print the contents. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, like so

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
objects = client.list_objects(Bucket='yourbucketnamegoeshere')
for obj in objects['Contents']:
    print(obj['Key'])
```

Done

Comment: client.list_objects(Bucket='yourbucketnamegoeshere')  is deprecated
instead use
client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='yourbucketnamegoeshere')